# Hide search highlight in VSCode Vim

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to switch from MacVim to VSCode and I use [VSCode Vim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) extension. The most annoying thing I found so far is: if I search with `/` command - I can't disable a highlighting of search results.

Could you pls help me to find a way how to hide search result highlighting after I've done with search?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found an answer:

in `settings.json`

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before":["<C-n>"],
        "after":[],
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": ":nohl"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: another version:
`"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [{
        "before": ["<leader>", "/"],
        "after": [],
        "commands": [":nohl"]
    }]`

Comment: If you want to toggle the highlighting, you can replace `:nohl` with `:set hlsearch!`

Answer (score 11):

Alternately, you can also just set `vim.hlsearch` to false.

Answer (score 6):

You can also just bind it to escape, which isn't bound to anything in normal mode.

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": [
            "<Esc>"
        ],
        "commands": [
            ":nohl"
        ],
    }
]
```